# ng-click to pass multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested json object array and I am able to display Inner Items grouped By Info in HTML using ng-repeat. I have a checkbox in front of each Inner Item where I am handling ng-click event and passing the selected Inner Items to the controller. But now I also wanted to pass Info id in the ng-click event. Can I concatenate the Info array to Inner items array in the ng-click

Here is the json :

```
[
  {
    "Info": {
      "id": "a1",
      "name": "a1-Info",
      "InnerInfo": [
        {
          "name": "xyz"
        }
      ]
    },
    "InnerItems": [ 
      { "id": "i1" }, 
      { "id": "i2" } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat=“I in MyData">
<td> {{I.Info.name}}
      <table>
             <tr><td>
                 <div ng-repeat=“item in I.InnerItems ">
                       <input type="checkbox" name="values" ng-click=“getInfo(I);getInnerItems(item)” ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"/>{{item.name}}
                 </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
       </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

I need to pass both arrays to one function instead of the above way. Any suggestions?

Comment: where is the code for the `ng-click` that you are having problems with?

Comment: not clear what you're trying to do, can you please show your code/logic?

Comment: Yes, please provide the code.

Comment: I have added the html code. I am able to get the InnerItems back into my controller but not Info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an expression with `ng-click` to set a property on the controller.

Say you have a property on the controller `activeData`, then use `ng-click` like this:

`ng-click="activeData = [I , item]"`

Comment: I am having 2 functions passed back to controller. One with the list of innerItems and the other containing Info. object. But I am only able to read inner items array in my controller but not the Info object

Comment: this is not an HTML `onclick` handler. This is `ng-click` - ng-click expects an expression such as `activeInfoItems = [I, item]` - where `activeInfoItems` would be a property on your controller that is set when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Go here:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick#usage click **Edit in Plunker**

Answer (score 0):

I have passed multiple parameters to one of my functions itself like getInfo (I, items) and tried to access in controller without having to use any property. It works fine